# Is it possible to return the bar_index of a PivotHigh in Pine Script 5?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'd like to set the index of **bar_index[]** based on **ta.pivothigh** in a dynamic way.

```
// PivotHigh Check
leftBars= input(4)
rightBars = input(4)
ph = ta.pivothigh(leftBars, rightBars)
plot(ph, style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=3, color=#ffffff, offset=-rightBars)

// Draw the line
upperLine = line.new(bar_index[10], high[10], bar_index[20], high[20], color=#ffffff, width = 2)
```

As you can see the numbers 10 and 20 aren't written in a dyinamic way, because I wrote the index of **bar_index** and **high**.
Is it possible to return the value of each circles made by **ta.pivothigh** in order to fill the index automatically?

Answer (score 1):

When your pivot is drawn, you are 'rigthBars' away from it.
So the index of your pivot is bar_index-rigthBars.

```
//@version=5
indicator("test", overlay = true)
var IndexNewPivot = 0
var IndexOldPivot = 0
// PivotHigh Check
leftBars= input(4)
rightBars = input(4)
ph = ta.pivothigh(leftBars, rightBars)
plot(ph, style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=3, color=color.purple, offset=-rightBars)

if ph > 0
    // Draw the line
    IndexNewPivot := bar_index - rightBars
    upperLine = line.new(IndexOldPivot, high[bar_index - IndexOldPivot], IndexNewPivot, high[bar_index - IndexNewPivot], color=color.blue, width = 2)
    IndexOldPivot := IndexNewPivot
```

The result :
[image]